# Adding SPF records when using both Google Workspace and SendGrid

Tags: email, spf, gmail, sendgrid

I previously didn't have any SPF set up on my domain. I use Google Workspace. I now use the SendGrid API.

This is what I set as the SPF record

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:_mailcust.gandi.net include:sendgrid.net ~all
```

SendGrid verified.

However on an email that was sent using Gmail I received a bounce back (email addresses redacted for security)

```
550 5.7.23 : Sender address rejected: Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Please see http://spf.libraesva.com/Why?s=mfrom;id=xxxx@xxxx.com;ip=209.85.218.45;r=xxxx@xxxx.com
```

And on that link it states...

```
...they need to change xxxx.com SPF record so that it authorizes mail-ej1-f45.google.com (209.85.218.45). They should add this to their SPF record:
a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com
```

But I am curious to know why I need to use `a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com` instead of or as well as `include:_spf.google.com`

I contacted Google support about this and they stated:

> If you're using sendgrid and Gmail and please add the below SPF
> records "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include include:sendgrid.net
> ~all"

But this is what I had already set as the SPF record and they haven't been much help since contacting them.

Currently my SPF looks like the following below but I'd like to know:

1. Why I have to add `a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com` to the SPF record
2. Can I have both `include:_spf.google.com` and `a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com` in the record?

   "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:_mailcust.gandi.net include:sendgrid.net a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com ~all"

Comment: Can you give us the actual domain in question? Your SPF record looks fine *on paper*, so I'm wondering if it's actually correctly in place. Ignore the generalized advice on that page; `mail-ej1-f45.google.com` is `209.85.218.45` which is included by `_netblocks.google.com` which is in turn included by `_spf.google.com`.

Comment: @ceejayoz apracticeforeverydaylife.com and that's interesting... Google support didn't seem to have a clue

Comment: I doubt the issue is on Google's end. How soon after the new SPF record did you get the bounce from Libraesva? Is it possible they just had the old record cached?

Comment: Maybe but on the link they sent it stated that the CURRENT SPF record was "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:_mailcust.gandi.net include:sendgrid.net a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com ~all"

Comment: I would not assume that help page and the actual mailserver in question use the exact same systems and caches. If you visit http://spf.libraesva.com/Why?s=mfrom;id=xxxx@xxxx.com;ip=209.85.218.45;r=xxxx@xxxx.com it does a lookup for `xxxx.com`, for example.

Comment: Perhaps. So are you saying that `include:_spf.google.com` should be enough and that `a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com` is fairly redundant?

Comment: Yes, that's redundant, because it's included in the IP ranges referenced by `_spf.google.com` already. Google sends email from many different IPs; that one just happened to be the one this particular email was sent from.

Comment: That's a good spot re the link for xxxx.com. When I sent a test email after changing the record it could've definitely been too quick and hadn't propagated yet. Should I remove `a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com` now?

Comment: It won't do any harm there, but it won't do any good. I'd remove so you don't go "wtf why" a year from now.

Answer (score 2):

This is not hard.

Find the address of mail-ej1-f45.google.com (its 209.85.218.45)
Lookup the TXT record for _spf.google.com:

"v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all"

Look up each of the listed records. Actually you only to check the first to find:

"v=spf1 ip4:35.190.247.0/24 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:108.177.8.0/21 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:216.58.192.0/19 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ~all"

mail-ej1-f45.google.com is in 209.85.128.0/17

So if you sent from a domain with SPF record containing "include:_spf.google.com" that failed for bad SPF then the issue is at the receiving end.